# Trying to get a list distinct values count per column in the same result column

Tags: c#, sql, linq

So for this example lets say I have a DataTable which is called dt and it has some number of columns, I want to get back a list of the column names and how many different values are in each column. Also I would like the result set ordered by the largest to the smallest

For example I have a table with 4 columns and 40 rows of data, in the first column there is 4 distinct values, second column 12, third column 20, fourth column 40. I want my result set to look like this

```
Column4 40
Column3 20
Column2 12
Column1 4
```

How could I achieve this using C# and Linq?

Comment: What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Can you get an `IEnumerable` of each column?  Can you get an `IEnumerable` of all of the values in a particular column?  Once you have that 2D `IEnumerable` the query itself is pretty simple?  Have you written that part?  Break the problem up into little pieces.  Solve the parts that you can and we can help with what you can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your LINQ code

```
var result = dt.Columns
    .Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Select(dc => new {
        Name = dc.ColumnName,
        Values = dt.Rows
            .Cast<DataRow>()
            .Select(row => row[dc])
            .Distinct()
            .Count()})
    .OrderBy(item => item.Values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result =
    dt.Columns
        .Cast<DataColumn>()
        .Select(c =>
            new
            {
                c.ColumnName,
                DistinctValuesCount =
                    dt.Rows
                        .Cast<DataRow>()
                        .Select(r => r[c])
                        .Distinct()
                        .Count()
            })
        .OrderByDescending(i => i.DistinctValuesCount)
        .ToArray();
```